# Do not parse specific tags using NSXMLParser

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

Consider the XML below:

```
<root>
    <bar>
        <p>Hello <italic>World</italic></p>
    </bar>
    <banjo><p>Hello <italic>World</italic></p></banjo>
</root>
```

I am currently using https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary to parse XML data. I would like to ignore `<p>` and `<italic>` tags. How can I achieve that?

NSDictionary should somehow look like this structure:

```
-root
--bar
---<p>Hello <italic>World</italic></p>
--banjo
---<p>Hello <italic>World</italic></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

So a quick glance at that [XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary) class seems to show that it just wraps the standard `NSXMLParser` and creates a convenient dictionary object with the *all* of the XML elements.

If you are committed to that github code, then you could potentially go through your resultant dictionary *after* parsing the XML and restructure the `<p>` and `<italic>` elements back into the parent element. But that's pretty inefficient and definitely not recommended unless you have very short XML and the benefit of the `XMLDictionary` class warrants the extra work.

You could also dig into the `XMLDictionary` code, specifically the `parser:didStartElement` and `parser:didEndElement` methods, and make some changes to ignore the `<p>` and `<italic>` tags. This should effectively flatten the structure to something close to your example result.

But, if you're considering poking around in that code, you might as well just use the `NSXMLParser` directly, ignoring those tags in the same way. This will give you tighter control over parsing and could reduce some unnecessary object creation, especially if your XML is of significant size. Just read up on [NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/) and even walk through the `XMLDictionary` code to see how it does the things you like about it.